# Function pointer not compiling cleanly

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to familiarize myself with pointers to functions in C. I have looked online and found several examples of these. However, when I compile my program (using GCC [version (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0]), I get several errors even though my code has an almost identical structure to that shown in the online examples.

For example, at [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) we have the following.

> Passing the pointer to another function is basically the same:
>
> ```c
> int add2to3(int (*functionPtr)(int, int)) {
>     return (*functionPtr)(2, 3);
> }
> ```

Whereas in my code I have the following function prototype. The numbers at the beginnings of lines refer to the line numbers in my code and help when referring to the error messages generated by GCC.

```c
28 double array_op(double array[], size_t size, double (*pfun)(double, double));
```

The corresponding function call is as follows.

```c
54 result = array_op(values, numberOfElements, (*pfun)(a, b)); // Calculate the sum
```

When I compile the program, this function call causes GCC to generate the following error message.

```
ex9_2.c: In function ‘main’:
ex9_2.c:54:49: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of ‘array_op’
   54 |    result = array_op(values, numberOfElements, (*pfun)(a, b)); // Calculate the sum
      |                                                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 double
ex9_2.c:28:55: note: expected ‘double (*)(double,  double)’ but argument is of type ‘double’
   28 | double array_op(double array[], size_t size, double (*pfun)(double, double));
      |                                              ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In line 54 I have varied the form of the function pointer using, in turn, the form shown above, as well as `(pfun)(a, b)`, `*pfun(a, b)`, and `pfun(a, b)`. All of these forms have resulted in the error message shown above.

My understanding is that the address of a primitive function (`add()`, `subtract()`, `multiply()`) is passed into function `array_op()` through `pfun` and that this is what causes each of the primitive functions to be applied, in turn, to pairs of elements from array `values[]`. As my usage of the function pointer has a very(!) similar structure to that shown in the stackoverflow example, I am at a loss to understand where I have gone wrong.

Given that this is my first time using function pointers, this is perhaps not surprising.

Could someone please help clarify my understanding so that I can correct my code?

Comment: `Passing the pointer to another function is basically the same` - you have quoted a function that accepts a function pointer, not passes it. In the terms of the [quoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840504/11683), you should pass `functionPtr` to it.

Comment: @GSerg: Thank you for your reply. This is a positive help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `result = array_op(values, numberOfElements, (*pfun)(a, b));`, `(*pfun)(a, b)` is not a pointer to a function. It is a call to a function. The correct code is `result = array_op(values, numberOfElements, pfun);`.

Putting arguments in parentheses after an expression forms a function call. So:

- `pfun` is a pointer to a function.
- `*pfun` designates that function.
- `(*pfun)` is the same thing, with grouping.
- `(*pfun)(a, b)` is a call to the function.

Given some pointer `p` to a function, `p` is the pointer, and `(*p)(…)` is a call to the function. The result of a call to the function is a value of the type returned by the function.

Also, you do not need to use `*` to call a function. The function call operator actually takes a pointer to a function, so `pfun(a, b)` is a correct function call. In `(*pfun)(a, b)`, the expression `(*pfun)` is automatically converted from the function back to a pointer to a function. In fact, if you write `(**pfun)(a, b)`, the `*pfun` will be converted to a pointer, then `*` produces the function it points to, and then that is also automatically converted to a pointer. This can continue indefinitely; `(*****pfun)(a, b)` will end up being just `pfun(a, b)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This has clarified things a good deal.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @Eric's answer here you have an example:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    printf("Func: %s ", __FUNCTION__);
    return x + y;
}

int sub(int x, int y)
{
    printf("Func: %s ", __FUNCTION__);
    return x - y;
}

int mul(int x, int y)
{
    printf("Func: %s ", __FUNCTION__);
    return x * y;
}

int divi(int x, int y)
{
    printf("Func: %s ", __FUNCTION__);
    int result = 0;
    if(y) result = x / y;
    return result;
}

int doSomething(int x, int y, int (*f)(int, int))
{
    return f(x,y);
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*func[])(int, int) = {add, sub, mul, divi};
    int x,y;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        x = rand(); y = rand();
        printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, doSomething(x, y, func[rand() % (sizeof(func) / sizeof(func[0]))]));
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fvE9zY8P4